# Trouble running basic Flask (ModuleNotFound Error)

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to begin working with Flask, but I'm having trouble getting started. I created a basic application just to get something going:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello World</h1>'

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

but whenever I try to run this via command line, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`. However, if I try to run the same set of code in a Jupyter notebook, it works perfectly fine.

I've installed everything via conda, and have tried inside the base environment and a separate virtual environment with `conda create -n myenv` and `conda install flask`.

I've tried uninstalling with `conda uninstall flask` in both the base environment and virtual environment and then reinstalling inside just the virtual environment. The environment should be active after `conda activate myenv`.

The package does appear using `conda list flask` showing it is version 2.2.2 of flask.

Per other posts, I've also tried simply activating the environment and doing `python` then `import flask` and this does not yield any errors.

Any suggestions to get the code to run from a file?

Edit:
Further, I have tried the following commands in order:

```
conda create -n myflaskenv flask
```

```
conda activate myflaskenv
```

```
conda run base.py
```

where `base.py` is simply

```
from flask import Flask
```

and receive the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Comment: How do you run the code ?

Comment: Looks like an issue in active environment. activate your conda virtual environment and  try `conda list` to get the list of packages.

Comment: @azro I'm running the file in the command line using `conda run base.py` where `base.py` is the name of the file.

Comment: @Towhid I mentioned I had the environment active using `conda activate myenv` and that using `conda list flask` shows flask as being installed. `conda list` of course does the same but with manually having to find it in the list

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check if the Flask package is installed in your local enviroment.

- use 'pip list' for that

Also it might help to check if you are on the right interpreter. So if you are on VSCode, press CTRL + Shift + P. Select 'Select Interpreter'. Check all of them one by one. Run the code on each of them( that is how you will find the right interpreter)

Good luck!

Comment: using `pip list` and `conda list` both show flask as being installed, both in the base environment and the virtual environment I created. I wasn't running the code in VSCode, but rather the command line using `conda run <filename>`, so I don't think the interpreter could be an issue (correct me if I'm wrong because I don't actually know)